# How to prove there is one possible value for $x$ in a univariable equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

**Motivation:** From what I've heard, if you have a system of $n$ equations, featuring $n$ variables, then it will typically be possible to derive a single value for each of the variables (whatever *typically* would mean in this context). Now, a question about how to prove whether or not this is the case for a system of equations would be interesting, but perhaps too broad/involved for a Q&A here. I have a feeling that for univariable equations, this question is a bit easier, and perhaps even more interesting. Thus, this is my question:

Certain univariable equations do not give a single value for $x$. Take the following two examples:

$$(x^2 = x^2) \implies (x \in \mathcal U) \tag1$$

$$ (x^2 = 5|x| + 3|x|)  \implies (x \in \{-8,8\}) \tag2$$

$$(x\times 0 = 5) \implies (x \notin \mathcal U) \tag 3$$

1. The first equation is a tautology; it offers no information (within any logic that assumes/derives the law of identity), and thus no information about $x$ with which one can pin-point its value. This type of univariable equations is trivially insufficient for giving a single value of $x$. The example I gave is a pure example of it, but any equation in which the variable is subjected to equivalent functions on the LHS and RHS, without the involvement of elucidating non-variables, would constitute an equation of this type, e.g.: $x^2 = (x/2)x + (x/2)x$.
2. The second equation utilizes functions on both sides of the equation sign that lack the same kind of information; thus, they are not able to make up for each other's deficiency in information.
3. The last equation contains a contradiction, which makes it undefined, and thus, in a completely different way, deprives $x$ of a single **value**, although giving it a single "status".

So, my question is this: **how do I determine whether a univariable equation (does not) give(s) a single value for $x$ without actually solving for $x$?**

Comment: Not quite sure what tags to use. I do not know what field of mathematics studies these kinds of questions. If anyone edits the question to have the right tags, I will delete this comment. I didn't want to clutter my question with this.

Comment: This might be completely unrelated, but this question reminded me of the famous Halting Problem which helped solve the other famous Decision Problem. You are asking for the existence of an algorithm that determines whether a univariable equation allows for the variable to take a singular value or not. I don't know if this is really germane, but I thought it was an interesting connection.

Comment: @BoredComedy I think its a very general connection to make, so it is germane, but perhaps trivially so. That said, I did think along the lines of the Halting Problem when conceiving of the question, because to me, the question has that feel to it. It's not about how to do something, but whether or not something can be done; it's not asking for algorithms, but a proof for the existence of them, which puts it into meta-mathematics. So yeah, kinda relevant I'd say :).

Comment: The fact that you can relate Turing Machines to second-order arithmetic means that you can almost certainly construct an equation where having a single solution is equivalent to the Halting Problem being true.